# Unable to open a page in a new window in an Electron + Nexjs (Nextron) app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, electron

I'm trying to open a (Nextjs-generated) page in a new window but I get the following error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` 
full error:

```
react-refresh.js?ts=1665849319975:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at react-refresh.js?ts=1665849319975:10:1
(anonymous) @ react-refresh.js?ts=1665849319975:10
webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:712 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:712:12
    at webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:1209:13
    at webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:1220:12
(anonymous) @ webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:712
(anonymous) @ webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:1209
(anonymous) @ webpack.js?ts=1665849319975:1220
main.js?ts=1665849319975:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at main.js?ts=1665849319975:9:1
(anonymous) @ main.js?ts=1665849319975:9
_app.js?ts=1665849319975:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at _app.js?ts=1665849319975:9:1
(anonymous) @ _app.js?ts=1665849319975:9
camera.js?ts=1665849319975:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at camera.js?ts=1665849319975:9:1
```

I have tried

```
import Link from 'next/link'
export default function Item(){
  <Link href="/camera">
    <a target="_blank">
      item
    </a>
  </Link>
}
```

and

```
import Link from 'next/link'
export default function Item(){
  <Link href="/camera">
    <a
      onClick={(e) => {
          window.open(
            "/camera",
            "_blank",
            "top=500,left=200"
          )
        }}>item
    </a>
  </Link>
}
```

Both result in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this problem is caused by the `contextIsolation` and `nodeIntegration` properties.

Re-writing the `window.open` following the method below, fixed the problem:

```
  window.open(
            "/camera",
            "_blank",
            "top=500,left=200,contextIsolation=no,nodeIntegration=yes"
            );
```

#### Why?

##### Context Isolation

> Context Isolation is a feature that ensures that both your preload scripts and Electron's internal logic run in a separate context to the website you load in a webContents.

[Context Isolation on Electronjs docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)

For example, if you set `window.hello = 'wave'` in your preload script and context isolation is enabled, `window.hello` will be `undefined` if the website tries to access it.

Therefore, the `global` object will be `undefined` in the new window. Setting  `contextIsolation=no` ensures that the `global` object is the same as the one previously set.

##### Node Integration

Node Integration is a way to help the new window access the nodejs properties like `__dirname`. This has to be enabled.